# HAProxy 1.4: how to replace X-Forwarded-For with custom IP

Tags: haproxy, amazon-elb

I have an HAProxy 1.4 server behind an AWS ELB. Logically, the ELB sends the users IP in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. My app reads that header and behaves differently based on the IP (country).

I want to test that behavior overriding the `X-Forwarded-For` with custom IPs, but the AWS ELB appends my custom value with my current IP (`X-Forwarded-For: 1.2.3.4, 200.1.130.2`)

What I have been trying to do is to send another custom header `X-Force-IP` and once it gets into HAproxy, delete `X-Forwarded-For` headers and use `reqirep` to change the name `X-Force-IP` to `X-Forwarded-For`

This is how my config chunk looks like

```
acl custom-ip hdr_cnt(X-Force-IP) 1
reqidel ^X-Forwarded-For:.* if custom-ip
reqrep X-Force-IP X-Forwarded-For if custom-ip
```

but when it gets into my app, the app server (lighttpd) rejects it with "HTTP 400 Bad Request" as if it were malformed.

```
[ec2-user@haproxy-stage]$ curl -I -H "X-Forwarded-For: 123.456.7.12" "http://www.example.com"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=mcs0tqlsg31haiavqopdvm02i6; path=/; domain=www.example.com
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Sun, 11 Jan 2015 02:57:34 GMT
Server: beta

[ec2-user@haproxy-stage]$ curl -I -H "X-Forwarded-For: 123.456.7.12" -H "X-Force-IP: 321.456.7.12" "http://www.example.com"
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 349
Date: Sun, 11 Jan 2015 02:57:44 GMT
Server: beta
```

From the previous it looks like the ACL is working.
I checked with **tcpdump** in the app server and it seems that it has deleted the `X-Forwarded-For` header but also deleted the `X-Force-IP` instead of replacing it.

```
[ec2-user@beta ~]# sudo tcpdump -A -s 20240 'tcp port 80 and (((ip[2:2] - ((ip[0]&0xf)<<2)) - ((tcp[12]&0xf0)>>2)) != 0)' | egrep --line-buffered "^........(GET |HTTP\/|POST |HEAD )|^[A-Za-z0-9-]+: " | sed -r 's/^........(GET |HTTP\/|POST |HEAD )/\n\1/g' 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 20240 bytes

GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 349
Connection: close
Date: Sun, 11 Jan 2015 02:56:50 GMT
Server: beta
```

The previous was with the `X-Force-IP`, and the following without it:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
Host: www.example.com
Accept: */*
X-Forwarded-For: 123.456.7.12
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.4
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 11 Jan 2015 02:57:02 GMT
Server: beta

^C71 packets captured
71 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Any help?
I was expecting to have "X-Force-IP: 321.456.7.12" converted into "X-Forwarded-For: 321.456.7.12"

Thanks!
Ignacio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex matching provided here doesn't do simple substitution. It's quite a bit more powerful, and has to be used accordingly.

```
reqrep ^X-Force-IP:(.*) X-Forwarded-For:\1 if custom-ip
```

The `reqrep` (case sensitive request regex replace) and `reqirep` (case insensitive request regex replace) directives operate at the individual request header level, replacing the header name *and its value* with the 2nd argument, if the 1st argument matches... so if there's information you want to preserve (such as the value) you need one or more capture groups, such as `(.*)`, in the 1st arg, and a placeholder `\1` in the 2nd arg, in order to do the preserve the data.

Your current configuration does indeed invalidate the request, by creating a malformed/incomplete header line.

Also, you should anchor the pattern to the left side of the header name with `^`.  Otherwise, the expression could match more headers than you expect.